# Returning local malloc() pointer from inside another function

Tags: c, malloc

I'm going through some [lecture slides](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr11/cos217/lectures/08DsAlg.pdf) from Princeton University and have a question. The professor has this code snippet (on slide 8 there):

```
struct Table *Table_create(void) {
 struct Table *t;
 t = (struct Table*)malloc(sizeof(struct Table));
 t->first = NULL;
 return t;
} 

struct Table *t;
…
t = Table_create();
…
```

In the `Table_crate()` function, even though `t` is allocated using `malloc`, `t` itself would be located on the stack, correct?.

So, can you return `t` from this function? I'd think `t` in `Table_create()` would disappear as soon as the function returns.

Comment: `malloc` is allocating on heap. I'ts perfectly fine to return it's result from a function. the only thing, that the prof should not cast the return result from `malloc`...

Comment: You didn't post `Table_crate()` function.

Comment: @MikeCAT I [found it (click)](http://midr.surlabreche.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Wooden-Crate-Coffee-Table.jpg)

Comment: Also, be sure check return value from `malloc`, as it may return _null pointer_ in case when it fails to allocate data (especially if function is to be called multiple times). Don't forget to call `free` after you are done with `t`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski yes, definitely check for null and free after use. I copied the sample code verbatim from the slides.

Comment: If someone voted down the question, could you please at least explain, why?

Comment: @rockford98: When writing C, _don't cast the return value of `malloc` and friends!_. That probably wasn't the reason for a down-vote, seems like someone just DV'ed every answer on this page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `t` has automatic storage duration. But that doesn't prevent you from returning its *value* from the function.
The value itself (i.e. the pointer returned by `malloc()`) has the lifetime of the program (or until you call `free()` on it). So, it's not an issue
to return the `malloc()`'ed value from a function.

If it helps, consider this:

```
int func(int num)
{
    int val;
    val = num * 2; //  take care of signed integer overflow!
    return val;
}
```

Does returning `val` here has anything to do with the lifetime of `val` (which is a local variable and has automatic storage duration)? No. This is analogous to `malloc()` code you have.

Comment: I think someone is playing games, everybody's answers were voted down :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `t` lives on the stack, but the thing it points to (via the call to `malloc`) lives on the heap.

When you return `t` you are returning it's value, which is the address on the allocated memory. This is then assigned to a local variable in the caller. If you hadn't assigned it in the caller you would have a memory leak. At some point you will need to call `free` in order to release the memory and avoid the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return *the value stored in* `t` because the value is copied to the caller, but you shouldn't return *pointers or references to* `t` because `t` will disappear and such pointers or references are useless.

Comment: Not sure how you're answer is any different than mine.'

Comment: @self I don't see how your answer is similar to Mike's.  This answer describes that it is OK to return `t` because it is copied, and this answer does not make the statement that "*`t` would not be on the stack*" which is not exactly correct and may be misleading.

Answer (score -1):

`t` would not be on the stack. You can return `t` from the function. `malloc` will remember the allocated memory until you call `free`

Comment: The local `t` will be on the stack in typical implementation, or it may be on the register.

Comment: malloc doesn't remember, the O/S remembers.

Comment: malloc maintains a linked list, at least glibc malloc does

Comment: @nicomp It may not be the O/S but the library in user space that remember the memory.

Comment: @self I mean `struct Table *t;` inside the function `Table_create()` by "local t".

Comment: The O/S doesn't trust user space to maintain the memory map.

Comment: @nicomp Typically, both the OS and the library (that provides `malloc`) maintain their own (separate) memory mapping, where the library relies on the OS.

Comment: im not speaking about what the std says, but about actually source code I've _seen_ in glibc

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've seen an implementation in System/360 I guess you've seen more than me so you win.